Are database connections automatically closed?
Our servers that run Drupal 10 site on Azure is experiencing too many active database connections and they are mostly in SLEEP state.
Do Drupal 10 modules automatically close database connections after a  connection is initialized, or does the active connection need to be closed?

PHP-FPM destructs the entire worker thread at the end of the request, so I can't see the need for it at all. This is not Drupal-specific, this is how PHP works.

If you have lots of sleeping connections, then your problem is lots of long running requests. Fix those and you fix your sleeping connections.

No. I suppose they don't close connections very well at the time I write this.

Drupal\Core\Database\Database::closeConnection() does not actually close [the] connection.


can I set something in the settings.php file to close connections? because there are ton of modules to check and was wondering if that was possible?

It's one question per post on this site.

PHP-FPM destructs the entire worker thread at the end of the request, so I can see neither the problem nor the need for Database::closeConnection() ... besides, yes, it is superfluent. The linked bug might exist, but IMHO is not relevant in the real world.
